# T-SQL function that returns a table data type. Wanting to traverse this table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, datatable

[This article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) returns all lines of an input file (.txt, .csv, etc.) but puts it into a table. I have this code:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    #MyTemp
FROM
    Dbo.uftReadfileAsTable('C:\test','test.txt.txt')
```

But isn't there an opportunity for efficiency here? `Dbo.uftReadfileAsTable('C:\test','test.txt.txt')` returns a table, but it has no name assigned for me to work with. I'm dreaming this up in my head, but I don't know the right syntax to handle this in the most efficient way:

```
Declare #T Table
Set #T = Dbo.uftReadfileAsTable('C:\test','test.txt.txt')
```

I know this is wrong. Just trying to see if I can do what I need in an efficient way. I can do anything I want with `#myTemp` to process it. For example, I want to do something like this, but in a loop:

```
Declare @Line varchar(Max)
SELECT
    @Line = Line from #MyTemp
WHERE
    [LineNo] = 1
--do something here with line...
DELETE FROM
    #MyTemp
WHERE
    [LineNo] = 1
```

Comment: It returns a read-only result exactly once. What exactly do you mean by "for me to work with it"? You can use it kind of _like_ a temp table, e.g. `WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tvf) work with cte;` but again it all depends on what you mean.\

Comment: Why do you need to treat this one row at a time, what do you do with `@Line`, and why do you then need to delete that row after you're done with it? Sounds like [an xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/165455) to me.

Answer (score 1):

The closest analog to what you're suggesting would be to declare a temporary table and `INSERT` into it from the tvf.  Alternately, for a single query you could use a CTE as per Aaron Bertrand's comment.

```
/* declare temporary table */
declare         
  @t                table(ColumnA       int unique not null,
                          ColumnB       Varchar(30) not null,
                          ColumnC       Varchar(30) null);

/* insert into temporary table */
insert @t(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
select * from Dbo.uftReadfileAsTable('C:\test','test.txt.txt');

/* returns rows temp table which were inserted from the tvf */
select * from @t; 

/* single query CTE */
with csv_cte as (
    select * from Dbo.uftReadfileAsTable('C:\test','test.txt.txt'))
select cc.* 
from csv_cte cc;
```

Comment: the purpose was to increase efficiency if possible.  so insert is not buying me anything.  as far as Aaron's approach, I don't think it is meant to be used where you have a bunch of code (not just one line) that is working on the Table that results from the function call...

Comment: @HillOfBeans The simple answer is we don't know. If the only details you'll offer is "I need to do a bunch of stuff" then we can't help you optimize "a bunch of stuff."

Comment: It seems as if you're suggesting to re-use a single use object.  It doesn't work like that. 
 There are a few ways to create durable temporary tables with different properties.  It all depends.  Your existing code uses SELECT INTO a locally scoped temporary table which might be inefficient because the assigned column types may not be appropriate.  Trying to be helpful

Comment: trying to iterate through. i edited the question, incase anybody know an answer.

Comment: "iterating through" is a last resort for SQL developers because it is the least efficient way to access rows in a table.  Only to be used when all other approaches have been exhausted.  We're not even close to being exhausted though.  Why not explain a little what you're trying to accomplish?  If it truly requires a loop then we'll do it.  But we have to try to avoid that first.

Comment: SteveC,  I am writing a program to read from any file type, and be able to import that data into a corresponding table, based on configuration tables.  For example, CSV, Position-based, etc.  Anything.  Just configure the input and define the destination.  Voila, it imports.  I am building that app.  So, I got a table back.  I need to iterate through each line to break it up and figure out how to put in destination.... I think my best bet is to tear out the code that does the import and use it as opposed to relying on the code I got as a function. People are mean.  This is a fair question.

Comment: It is a fair question.  Sounds like a interesting project.  The [function](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/uftReadFileAsTable.txt) is from an article that pre-dates SQL features like openrowset and opendatasource.  Bigger picture I see many potential issues with the starting point of the data flow being SQL Server.  SQL is finicky about what files it will open and what encodings it will read.  CSV file in particular it's finicky.

Comment: C#'s base type is 'object' which is literally anything.  The C# library CSVHelper is the best bet imo for opening almost any CSV file no matter how poorly formatted

Comment: There's a WHILE loop in Phil Factor's function.  You could extend on that